# Util-Linux Login not working with shadow password

Tags: linux, login

I downloaded `util-linux-2.12b` package and and built it. I need to use the `login` utility in the `login-utils` folder.

But after running it, it gives a "Login incorrect" for every user even with correct username/password.

---

Now it seems the utility is not working with /etc/shadow passowrds.

if I disable the shadow passwords by

```
#pwunconv
```

Its is working fine, while after enabling it with

```
#pwconv
```

It stops working again. :(

Comment: Why aren't you using CentOS packages?

You should paste some relevant log lines and configuration into your question, as your question currently says "login doesn't work. fix it." We need to know what login is doing and how it is set up.

Comment: David, I have modified the question with latest pointer i have on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you built the package with the source RPM? Seems that you might have compiled it by hand (the tar.gz) without shadow password supprt, which will explain the fact that when disabling shadow password it works.

If you do it with a source RPM you should install it, extract the util-linux sources (under /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES), patch and close it up again. Another, even better option is to add your patch to the spec file and then build.

Comment: I did build it using the .tar.gz package, I did not find any configuration documentation.. even ./configure --help isn't working. Can you please suggest how to enable shadow passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if use RHEL that will have all you require. Or you can look form lfs project were open source ppl are there to help with code.

rajat

Comment: I am using RHEL, and I have downloaded their source code as i need to patch something. But this problem is inherent in it even in the untouched version.

I gues there are people here to help me too! :)

Comment: Mohit have u use H/W is certify from RHEL and ver are using bcoz i was faceing a same pro with my old laptop using RHEL 5.2 update (desktop)..Rajat